# Run ANT on Ubuntu with proprietary Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant

I have some trouble running ANT on Ubuntu. I know that there are tons of posts about it but I've never found a post about proprietary Java. So, when I try to launch ANT, I got this error :

> jeff@jeff-X200MA:~$ ant
>   Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /opt/jre1.7.0_51/lib/tools.jar
>   Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
>   Build failed

What can I do to fix that ?

Thank you in advance :),
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0):

[**HERE**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup) is the entire instructions for installing and running `Ant`.

- you need to install `jdk` (available [**here**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)) and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to jdk's installation directory and add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to the `PATH`variable. See [**HERE**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for setting environment variables.
- similarly, you need to install `Ant` and set `ANT_HOME` environment variable to Ant's installation directory and add `%ANT_HOME%/bin` to the `PATH` variable. See the *1st Link*, at the start.
- close any open `command-prompt` windows, to reflect the changes.

---

When you need `JDK` functionality (such as for the `<javac>` task or the `<rmic>` task) in `Ant`, then `tools.jar` is required. This *tools.jar* is present in `JDK` but not in `JRE`. See JDK and JRE [**file Structure**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)

currently your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to, probably, `/opt/jre1.7.0_51` and thus, while *running ant* it is searching for *tools.jar* under the `/opt/jre1.7.0_51/lib` folder. you need to *install* `jdk` if you haven't and change `JAVA_HOME` to point to the installation directory of *JDK*, for eg. `/opt/jdk1.7.0_60`.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I'm going to test that right now !

Comment: I have another problem. I've done what you told me to do but when I close my command-prompt window, the terminal doesn't know the java command whereas before I close it, it worked. It's as if the PATH is not saved when I close the window. I've done these commands to change my path :

        PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_65/bin:$PATH
        export PATH

And I've done the same thing for ANT. How can I fix it ?
Thanks again for your answer

Comment: See http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-sun-java-jdk-and-setting-java_home-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: THe path works correctly but I still have the error concerning the build.xml file. How can I fix it ?

Comment: what command do you use to launch the build? (be exact)